# Set option element as selected based on two queries

Tags: php, html

I am trying to figure out how to mark a dropdown option as selected by checking it's value, but the value is coming from another query.

I get the `$FK_TopicID` from the query called `$quickedit`. The dropdown list is generated by a different query called `$topresult`. I have an IF/ELSE statement that is supposed to print `SELECTED` inside of the option like `<option value="the Topic ID" SELECTED>` when the `$FK_TopicID` is equal to `$row['TopicID']`.

I am just not sure how to check the `$FK_TopicID` within the `while` loop for `$topresult`. Any ideas?

```
    <?php

       $NewsID = $_GET["n"];
       $quickedit = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM News LEFT JOIN Topics on Topics.TopicID = News.FK_TopicID WHERE NewsID = $NewsID ORDER BY TopicName ASC, NewsTitle");
       $row = mysql_fetch_array($quickedit);

    echo "<p>" . $FK_TopicID . "</p>";

    /* additional php... */

    $topresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Topics WHERE FK_UserID=$_SESSION[user_id] ORDER BY TopicSort, TopicName");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($topresult)) {
                if ( $row['TopicID'] == $FK_TopicID){ /* $FK_TopicID not printing value here */
                   $selected = " SELECTED";
                } else {
                   $selected = "";
                }
                echo '<option value=\"' . $row['TopicID'] . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $row['TopicName'] . '</option>';
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: Why would you expect `$FK_TopicID` to print there? You have not called any `print` or `echo` on it.  By the way, please do `$NewsID = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['n']);` Your script is open to tampering via SQL injection as it is now.

Comment: You are vulnerable to SQL injection, please either sanitize (e.g. `intval()`) or escape (e.g. `mysql_real_escape_string()`) anything your get from the `_GET`

Comment: Can you update your question with how you got `$FK_TopicID`? You say it comes from the `$quickedit` query but don't actually show how you set it.

Comment: Michael: I guess that is part of my question. Can I print or echo a variable from another query within a WHILE clause? I would think PHP would look for this variable from the $topresult query since that is what the WHILE clause is referring to, e.g. while($row = mysql_fetch_array($topresult)). How can I let PHP know that the variable is from another query?

Comment: MattCan: I did show the $quickedit query above. Maybe I misunderstood your post. I print some variables in a form, e.g. <input value="<?php echo $row['NewsTitle']?>" type="text" name="NewsTitle" />

Comment: Michael & Shad: I will utilize mysql_real_escape_string as suggested.

Comment: Your hints helped me to solve it. Since I had $row declared twice, I changed the first iteration to $quickrow = mysql_fetch_array($quickedit). Then, I was able to specify the following: if ( $row['TopicID'] == $quickrow['FK_TopicID'])

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue about the structures of the database, but I'll give it a shot

Does this output something you want?

```
<?php
$NewsID = $_GET['n'];
$quickedit = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM News LEFT JOIN Topics on Topics.TopicID = News.FK_TopicID WHERE NewsID = $NewsID ORDER BY TopicName ASC, NewsTitle");
$topresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Topics WHERE FK_UserID=$_SESSION[user_id] ORDER BY TopicSort, TopicName");

echo "<p>" . $FK_TopicID . "</p>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($quickedit)) {
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($topresult)) {
        if ( $row2['TopicID'] == $row['FK_TopicID']){
           $selected = " SELECTED";
        } else {
           $selected = "";
        }
        echo '<option value=\"' . $row2['TopicID'] . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $row['TopicName'] . '</option>';
    }
}

?>
```

This code loops through both queries and if the `TopicID` from `$topresult` is equal to the `FK_TopicID` from `$quickedit`, it will be selected.